# Ordering of events in the Developer Story

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I have been working at a company since June 2015, and have a career milestone at this company which was the delivery of a new version of their platform in November of last year.

In the Developer Story, the milestone appears 'before' (lower) the job that the milestone is in:

[image]

In the above screenshot the milestone is highlighted on the left-hand side and the job is highlighted on the right-hand side. The job starts in June 2015 and is still going, while the milestone was in November.

Is this a bug or am I misusing the developer story system?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was a bug as Today > November 2017 but it does look odd.

Comment: Experience entries are ordered by end date. Your current position has an end date of "Current", which is more recent than "November last year", as @George points out. I personally believe this is the Right Thing. Imagine you're still in your same job in several years' time: your big project in November would now be _ages ago_ and it'd make perfect sense to put your current job higher in the list.